# Finding average distance from a number to a set of numbers using only properties (average, variance, etc.) of the set

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a positive number $P$ and a set of positive numbers $S$ and I want to find the average distance from $P$ to each of the numbers in $S$. More concretely, I want to find:

$$
AD = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{\lvert S\rvert} \lvert S_k - P \rvert}{\lvert S\rvert}
$$

However, I have a few numbers $P$ and I'd like to avoid going through $S$ more than once.

If $P$ is either less than or greater than the smallest or largest number in $S$ respectively, I believe we can use the average of the numbers in $S$ to find the average distance:

$$
AD = |average(S) - P| \impliedby P \le min(S) \vee P \ge max(S)
$$

However, this falls apart when $min(S) \lt P \lt max(S)$.

Is there any finite set of properties (average, variance, min, max, etc.) of the numbers in $S$ we can keep track of to calculate the average directly (without going through S) for any (positive) value of $P$?

This is mainly for enrichment - I would like to know if this is possible as described.

Comment: It is not clear to me what "the average number in S" means.  Do you mean the average of the numbers in S (the average will not generally be a number in S)? You say "correct me if I'm wrong": have you verified your claim with a few examples?

Comment: @MatthewConroy Yes, I mean the average of the numbers in S. I did verify it with a few examples.

Comment: You can prove your claim by noting that, if $P$ is less than the smallest element of $S$, then $|S_k-P|=S_k-P$ so the sum is equal to $\sum S_k-P|S|$ and so AD =average$(S)-P$.  Likewise if $P$ is greater than the largest element of $S$.